# error enabling adsense management api

Tags: api, adsense, adsense-api

I am trying to enable the adsense management api from the google developers console. I have created a project and under APIs and auth I go to APIs and try to turn on AdSense Management API, but when I click it it just shows a toast notification saying "Error Enabling Adsense Management API". I really need this to work. So help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project and enabling it there? I've seen some situations where certain projects misbehave, while others work fine.

Comment: Yes i tried in the new project .

Comment: As one of the answers suggests, have you tried a different browser/incognito window?

Comment: Tried a different browser here, same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using a different browser or going back to the old version of the console? I had a similar issue because the browser blocked the Terms of Service agreement page.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I disabled my AdBlocker. Then it worked just fine!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Disable AdBlock plugin and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Open a new incognito window and open the console url "https://console.developers.google.com/" there. After that, activate the AdSense Management API.